# Magento displays "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time" when the postal code have letters

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout

i run a Magento CE Shop v1.7.0.2.

When customers trying to checkout with letters in the postal code (like netherlands) they getting: "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time"

Without letters and whitespace there is no problem.

The other posts about this problem are about things with ups, fedEx etc... i dont have something active like this.

I only got multi tablerates and tablerates active. All countries allowed.

can someone explain to me where i can fix this? for the first time a temporary change on core classes would be ok till i get a reasonable solution.

I try to ask another way:

Where does magento decide which qotes available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export the tablerates.csv file in System Config > Sales > Shipping methods > Table rates. For the Netherlands the format should be like this (unless you use weight or size as well):

```
NLD,*,,0.0000,10.0000
NLD,*,,80.0000,0.0000
```

In this example you get free shipping from 80 euros up, and below that you have to pay 10 euros for shipping. For province the setting should be *, for postcode nothing between the commas. If you use a range for the postcode, that might explain your problem.